# Kurento Group call example: Get access to individual user pipeline

Tags: kurento

In java group call application example, how can I get access to each user's kurento mediapipeline. Is it possible to get a hold of individual pipeline?

When I print the `Id` of evey connected user's mediapipeline I get the same output

```
user1: b524a269-cef8-4070-99d4-e8895b7e6fb8_kurento.MediaPipeline
user2: b524a269-cef8-4070-99d4-e8895b7e6fb8_kurento.MediaPipeline
```

When we create WebRtcEndpoint we use something like `this.outgoingMedia = new WebRtcEndpoint.Builder(pipeline).build();`

here the `pipeline` object is same for all `UserSession()`

I want to apply my filter on each user's mediapipeline. Is it possible ?

**Edit1:**

here we are using `pipeline` in `UserSession()` to get the  outgoing 
WebRtcEndpoint

```
this.outgoingMedia = new WebRtcEndpoint.Builder(pipeline).build();
```

and this is how I connect my filter to the out going webrtcendpoint's mediapipeline.

```
VADCustomFilter vadfilter = new  VADCustomFilter.Builder(this.outgoingMedia.getMediaPipeline(), name).build();
this.outgoingMedia.connect(vadfilter);
```

**Edit 2:**

solved the issue, I was setting user name when creating the filter object and then sending this username when raising events, now I am setting tags on the filter object and getting this tag when reveicing the event which is giving proper output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline is the same as only elements in the same pipeline can be connected.

Is perfectly possible to add a filter to each input, but this may required modifying the connections that are being created when a new user arrives.

Comment: Not trivial, you need more elements (your filter) and then also take care that media is connected this way: WebRTC -> FIlter -> RemoteWebRTC

Comment: okay, but the `WebRTC` endpoint which is separate for each user uses the same media pipeline created once for the entire group. Thus the `pipeline` being the same I'm getting events from the filter but not able to map it with individual piepeline

Comment: You should be able to filter events using the source of the event (Gstreamer element). Isn't it that enough?

Comment: when creating the filter object I am passing the user's name as a parameter and then applying it to the pipeline, and when I am raising the event I am sending this username a a parameter which will distinguish between users but as the filter applied on `this.outgoingMedia.getMediaPipeline()` I am getting callbacks only from the last user connected to the group call.

Comment: How are you rising the events exactly? If you have a look at zbar filter, https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/blob/master/src/server/implementation/objects/ZBarFilterImpl.cpp#L19 it is getting bus messages and is able to raise events correctly even when you have multiple filters on the same pipeline.

Comment: solved the issue, I was setting user name when creating the filter object and then sending this username when raising events, now I am setting tags on the filter object and getting this tag when reveicing the event which is giving proper output

Comment: Please don't link questions in comments, I'm subscribed to kurento tag so I already receive notifications.